# npm registry out of date - always says no compatible version found for new versions

Tags: node.js, npm

Whenever I try to install an up to date package (e.g. glob@7.0.6), npm complains saying the version doesn't exist. Sample output:

```
npm ERR! No compatible version found: glob@7.0.6
npm ERR! Valid install targets:
npm ERR! 7.0.5, 7.0.4, 7.0.3, 7.0.1, 7.0.0, 6.0.4, 6.0.3, 6.0.2, 6.0.1, 5.0.15, 5.0.14, 5.0.13, 5.0.12, 5.0.11, 5.0.10, 5.0.9, 5.0.7, 5.0.6, 5.0.5, 5.0.4, 5.0.3, 5.0.2, 5.0.1, 5.0.0, 4.5.3, 4.5.2, 4.5.1, 4.5.0, 4.4.2, 4.4.0, 4.3.5, 4.3.4, 4.3.3, 4.3.2, 4.3.1, 4.3.0, 4.2.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.6, 4.1.5, 4.1.4, 4.1.3, 4.1.2, 4.1.2-beta, 4.0.6, 4.0.5, 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 4.0.2, 4.0.1, 4.0.0, 3.2.11, 3.2.10, 3.2.9, 3.2.8, 3.2.7, 3.2.6, 3.2.5, 3.2.4, 3.2.3, 3.2.1, 3.2.0, 3.1.21, 3.1.20, 3.1.19, 3.1.18, 3.1.17, 3.1.16, 3.1.15, 3.1.14, 3.1.13, 3.1.12, 3.1.11, 3.1.10, 3.1.9, 3.1.7, 3.1.6, 3.1.5, 3.1.4, 3.1.3, 3.1.2, 3.1.1, 3.1.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.0, 2.1.0, 2.0.9, 2.0.8, 2.0.7, 1.1.0
```

However, if I check the npm website, glob is currently at 7.1.0. 7.0.6 was released in August. I get this issue for many packages, not just glob. It's like my local npm registry was frozen around June and doesn't recognise anything that was done since then. The weird thing is if I run `npm install` inside a vagrant box on my machine, it will install the latest version without issues but if I do it in the OSX environment, I get that error.

Comment: Try running `npm cache clean`

Answer (score 0):

Just remembered I installed npm localcache in July..

Deleted my ~/.npmrc and all works well again.